# data.table j expression on each .SD return a list of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I just started using data.table and something confuses me..

In using .SD, as long as j-expression returns a list, each element of the list should be converted to a column in the resulting data.table.

However, I realize that if an element of the list is a data.table, this won't work.

```
# this function returns a list of data.tables
foo = function(dt){
  return(list(a = dt[1:2, 1], 
              b = dt[3, 1:2]))
}

# this function returns a list of numbers
bar = function(dt){
  return(list(a = 1, b = 2))
}
```

And when I tried these functions:

```
ir = as.data.table(iris)

ir[, bar(.SD), by = Species] 
# this works, a and b are split into 2 columns nicely

ir[, foo(.SD), by = Species]
#this doesn't work, giving me an error:
#Error in `[.data.table`(ir, , foo(.SD), by = Species) : All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists.
```

From what I understand, the two data.tables in foo()'s return list should be turned into two columns, with each column being a data.table.

Why this doesn't happen? If it's deliberately designed this way, what is the reason?

---

Edit: If I do

```
ir[, .(foo(.SD)), by = Species]
```

each element returned in foo() will be turned into a row (6 rows, 1 column, 2 rows each Species). But I want each of them being in a column (3 rows, 2 column, 1 row each Species). Is there a way to do so in data.table?

Comment: You need to wrap it in a `list` as the columns needs to be same length and by doing this kind of data.table as a column output, it wouldn't fit in.  Check `ir[, list(list(.SD[1:2, 1], .SD[3, 1:2])), by = Species]$V1`

Comment: this way the original list returned by foo() will be concatenated, so that each element (.SD[1:2,1], .SD[3,1:2]) becomes a row in result data.table. Is there a way to make each element a column?